# How to pipe program output to the screen AND to a file under Windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch-file

I have a command which I need to inspect in real time (i.e. see its output in the command prompt *MyProgram.exe*) and to have a log file for later inspection (*MyProgram.exe > log.txt*)

How can I make a single instance of the program to write to both outputs?

Comment: See [same question on stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/dos-command-to-display-result-on-console-and-redirect-the-output-to-a-file)

Comment: Closed due to the high number of low quality, "use this product" answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either use one of many [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) [clones for Windows](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+tee).

Or if you're using PowerShell, you can use [Tee-Object](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/msh/cmdlets/tee-object.mspx).

Comment: maybe you could demo this?

Answer (score 4):

You want a unix tee clone like [this one](http://www.chipstips.com/?p=129) or [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/khen1234/archive/2005/10/27/486031.aspx).  I'm sure there are others, but, well, your Google for 'windows tee' is as good as mine.